# Angular/Typescript/RxJS - how to add an extra item to an incoming array

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a block of RxJS code where I am transforming a list of json objects into a list of items to populate a drop down list.

```ts
this.folders$ = this.folderStore.folders$.pipe(
  map((folders: GdFolder[]) => {
    const data = folders.map(folder => ({
      label: folder.name,
      value: folder.idStr()
    }));
    this.taskForm.get('folder').patchValue(this.NO_FOLDER_FILTER);
    return data;
  })
);
```

However,  I want to add an extra item to the transformed list to represent a 'no selection' entry. How do I adapt the RxJS code so that it can return one more entry than is in the original array?

Answer (score 1):

You can add an element to your array like below:

```ts
this.folders$ = this.folderStore.folders$.pipe(
  map((folders: GdFolder[]) => {
    const data = folders.map(folder => ({
      label: folder.name,
      value: folder.idStr()
    }));
    data.unshift({label: 'no selection', value: 'what you want'});
    // unshift method add the element at the top of the list.
    this.taskForm.get('folder').patchValue(this.NO_FOLDER_FILTER);
    return data;
  })
);
```